# BeautifulSoup my for loop is printing all the data from the td tag. I would like to exclude the last section of the td tag

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have the following sample HTML table from a html file.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Class</th>
        <th class="failed">Fail</th>
        <th class="failed">Error</th>
        <th>Skip</th>
        <th>Success</th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Regression_TestCase.RegressionProject_TestCase2.RegressionProject_TestCase2</td>
            <td class="failed">1</td>
            <td class="failed">9</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>219</td>
            <td>229</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
        <td class="failed">1</td>
        <td class="failed">9</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>219</td>
        <td>229</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to print the text from the `<td>` tags where `<td>` starts from:
    Regression_TestCase.RegressionProject_TestCase2.RegressionProject_TestCase2

I do not want to include the text from the `<td>` tags where `<td>` starts from:

```
<td><strong>Total</strong></td>
```

My code is printing the text from every single `<td>` tag:

```
def extract_data_from_report():
    html_report = open(r"E:\SeleniumTestReport.html",'r').read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_report, "html.parser")
    th = soup.find_all('th')
    td = soup.find_all('td')

    for item in th:
        print item.text,
    print "\n"
    for item in td:
        print item.text,
```

My desired output:

```
Class               Fail Error Skip Success Total 
Regression_TestCase 1    9     0    219     229
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all rows (`tr` elements) except the first one (to skip the headers) and the last one - the "total" row. Sample implementation that produces a list of dictionaries as a result:

```
from pprint import pprint

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = """
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Class</th>
        <th class="failed">Fail</th>
        <th class="failed">Error</th>
        <th>Skip</th>
        <th>Success</th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Regression_TestCase.RegressionProject_TestCase2.RegressionProject_TestCase2</td>
            <td class="failed">1</td>
            <td class="failed">9</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>219</td>
            <td>229</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
        <td class="failed">1</td>
        <td class="failed">9</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>219</td>
        <td>229</td>
    </tr>
</table>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

headers = [header.get_text(strip=True) for header in soup.find_all("th")]
rows = [dict(zip(headers, [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.find_all("td")]))
        for row in soup.find_all("tr")[1:-1]]

pprint(rows)
```

Prints:

```
[{u'Class': u'Regression_TestCase.RegressionProject_TestCase2.RegressionProject_TestCase2',
  u'Error': u'9',
  u'Fail': u'1',
  u'Skip': u'0',
  u'Success': u'219',
  u'Total': u'229'}]
```

Comment: That's great.  Thank you.  How can i put all the text on 1 line.  The numbers on the next new line.  The numbers should be below each text.  E.g. 9 should be underneath Error.  1 should be underneath Fail.

Comment: @RiazLadhani okay, could you provide an example desired output? Thanks.

Comment: Please see my question. I have amended the desired output at the end of my question. Thanks.

Comment: @RiazLadhani ah, got it. I think you should look into pretty-printing in a tabular form: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/python-printing-lists-as-tabular-data, or use the pandas dataframe that can also be "table-printed"..hope that helps.